# Why Incrementing Array name works in this case?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've learned that array name is treated like a const pointer, and thus it cannot be incremented. However, I found that it works under this condition: when array is passed as an argument of a function, inside the function, name of the array can be incremented. can some explain me why this works?

Here is the code:

```
using namespace std;
unsigned int c_in_str(const char* str, char ch);
int main()
{

    char mmm[15] = "minimum";
    unsigned int ms = c_in_str(mmm, 'm');
    cout << "m counts: " <<ms;
    return 0;
}

// this function counts the number of ch characters    
unsigned int c_in_str(const char* str, char ch)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (*str)        // quit when *str is '\0'
    {
        if (*str == ch)
            count++;
        str++;        // how come this works with array name?
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: An array is a const pointer, whereas here you have a pointer to const, which you can increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true you cannot increment an array but `str` is a pointer not an array.

You can tell by looking at the decalration `const char* str`. The strange thing is that even if you change the declaration to this `const char str[]` then `str` is still a pointer. It's impossible to have an array as a parameter in C++ (or C).

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you